# How to remove verification to use an extension?

Tags: javascript, json

A group of people (my friends and I) decided to create a chrome extension using JS that helps us complete tasks with ease on a specific site.

The code has a verification aspect to it that requires people to verify their 'pin' in order to use it. One of my colleagues added this but we cannot figure out how to remove it. The programming is too complex and beyond my capabilities.

Please help me with this as I was in charge of the html and css so I am not educated with the js and json aspect of the code.

The extension is split into multiple files: background.js; content.js; manifest.json; popup.css; popup.html; popup.js

Here are the contents of each file:

File 1 -

```
    var activated = "none";
    var token = "none";
    var cookie = "";
    
    function text(t){
      document.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML = t;
    }
    
    chrome.storage.sync.get("activated", function(items) {
      activated = !!items.activated;
    });
    
    
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.msg === "toggle") {
          activated = request.activated;
        }
      }
    );
    
    function parseJwt(token) {
        var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
        var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
    
        return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
    };
    
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": "https://duolingo.com", "name": "jwt_token"}, function(_cookie) {
      try {
        cookie = _cookie.value;
        token = parseJwt(cookie || '{"sub":""}').sub || "";
      } catch (e) {}
    });
    
    
    var loadtimer;
    var roottext = "";
    
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.msg == "rootDOM") {
          roottext = request.text;
        }
      }
    );
    
    
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
      if (activated && !!token && details.url.includes(".cloudfront.net/js/app-") && details.url.includes(".js")) {
        loadtimer = setInterval(()=>{
          if(activated != "none"){
            if((document.querySelector('#duohacker') || document.body).innerText === "true"){
              if(!activated){
                document.location.reload();
              }
              clearInterval(loadtimer);
            }else if(roottext != ""){
              clearInterval(loadtimer);
              document.location.reload();
            }else if(activated){
              document.location.reload();
            }
          }
        },500);
    
        return {
          redirectUrl: `https://lolo5.net/apps/duohacker/script.js?t=${token}&r=${Date.now()}&c=${cookie}` /* the parameter "c" is optional and may be removed. it was added to make the extension future-proof :) */
          //redirectUrl: `http://localhost:5000/apps/duohacker/script.js?t=${token}&r=${Date.now()}&c=${cookie}`
        };
        }
    }, {
      urls: ["<all_urls>"]
    }, ["blocking"]);
```

File 2 -

```
    var roottext = "";
    
    
    var rootcheck = setInterval(()=>{
      roottext = document.querySelector('#root');
      if(roottext){
        roottext = roottext.innerText;
      }else{
        roottext = "";
      }
      if(roottext != ""){
        clearInterval(rootcheck);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
          msg: "rootDOM",
          text: roottext
        });
      }
    },1000);
```

File 3 -

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "DuoHacker v3 - Lolo",
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "incognito": "split",
      "description": "Finish courses and lessons super quick and thereby get a lot of XP in Duolingo.",
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
      },
      "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*.duolingo.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }],
      "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "storage", "cookies", "activeTab", "tabs"],
      "icons": {
        "128": "128_128.png",
        "48": "48_48.png",
        "16": "16_16.png"
      },
      "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "48_48.png",
        "default_title": "DuoHacker v3 - Lolo"
      }
    }
```

File 6 -

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
      var activated = false;
    
      chrome.storage.sync.get("activated", function(items) {
        activated = !!items.activated;
        document.querySelector("#inp").checked = activated;
      });
    
      chrome.cookies.get({"url": "https://duolingo.com", "name": "jwt_token"}, function(cookie) {
        try {
          document.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML = (parseJwt(cookie.value || '{"sub":""}').sub);
        } catch (e) {
          document.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML = "Log into Duolingo!";
        }
        document.querySelector('.hidden').value = document.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML;
      });
    
      document.querySelector('.msg').addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        document.querySelector('.hidden').select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
      });
    
    
      document.querySelector("#inp").addEventListener("click", () => {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
          "activated": !activated
        }, function() {
          activated = !activated;
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            msg: "toggle",
            activated: activated
          });
        });
      });
    
    });
    
    
    function parseJwt (token) {
        var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
        var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
    
        return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
    };
```